# Is it possible to add 2 monitor to Dell XPS 15 Laptop?

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors, dell-xps

Is it possible to add 2 monitor to this [Dell XPS 15 Laptop](http://www.dell.com/us/p/xps-15/pd) ?

[image]

[image]

**Mini DisplayPort (1)**

**2 total USB 3.0**

**HDMI 1.4**

Do we need to buy extra hardware for this?

[image]

Comment: were you able to use two external monitors with Dell Xps L502X?

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can, at least according to [this forum thread](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19351083.aspx) (about two thirds down)

Relevant bit quoted:

> YES, it is possible to connect two external screens to XPS 15. However, you need to disable the embedded laptop screen for the time being. You may NOT be able to configure it using your Win7 "Personalize" context-menu option nor by using keyboard but it can be easily done via NVIDIA Control Panel (use the checkboxes).

Comment: I found this and I think with Adaptor I would be able to use all 3 screen http://www.matrox.com/graphics/en/products/gxm/th2go/

Answer (score 3):

you can easily connect two dell monitors to an xps15.  I have two full hd monitors connected to  my xps15, one by the HDMI socket and one by vga using a £10 displayport to vga adaptor off ebay which allows a standard vga lead to plug into it.  Interestingly the displays are crisper than they were with my old laptop running the same setup.  Window layout is fully configurable and I think you may be able to run laptop screen at same time as well if you really wanted to.  Make sure you buy the right displayport adaptor as there are computers needing subtly different versions which do not work.  Note I do not run my sound through the monitors.

Comment: Forgot to mention, when I reboot or wake from hibernation my win system it automatically switches to the monitors, no need for any usb adaptors which any poster recommended

Comment: Could you get it to work with the built-in display as well? So 3 displays simultaneously?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what kind of hardware you're willing to attach, you can probably get 8 or more external monitors running on this, although I can't guarantee what kind of performance you'll have.  (That would be some combination of USB->DVI adapters, an ExpressCard-to-PCIe video card chassis, a Matrox-Triple-Head-2-Go, or something like that.)

More realistically, if you only want to use the internal ports you can get both if you disable the laptop screen.  If you ONLY want two monitors and the laptop screen, and you don't need super high resolution or any 3D performance, just get a USB video adapter for the second external.

Answer (score 2):

I am running XPS L521x 15" laptop display at full HD with two 23" displays at full HD.
System configuration as purchased:

OS: `Win 8 x64`
Video: `NVIDIA GeForce GT 640M 2GB GDDR5 VRAM`

I find that using the 15" laptop display in the center and extending displays to the left and right creates a very efficient and ergonomic workspace. Displays all sit on the desk close to the front with wireless keyboard and mouse on the keyboard pullout shelf which is slightly lower. The laptop on a small tilt stand that centers the display and raises it up a bit. (a book under the rear of the laptop does the same thing)

I move a lot between my home office, work office, and a customer site all in different states - each with two monitors on the desk. So I can set up and be productive instantly without a lot of fuss over special stands or other video gizmos to accomplish the setup.

Comment: Is this answering the question though, meaning how to achieve it; I don't believe the OP asked about comfort!

Comment: I have XPS L421X 14". I've been trying to connect 2 displays (HDMI-HDMI and HDMI-Mini DiplayPort), but I just cannot make them work simultaneously. Windows sees 3 displays connected (including laptop's), but only two of them can be active (turned on) at a time. Did you encounter this issue?

Comment: @nazikus That is actually a hardware limitation, not just Windows - see http://askubuntu.com/questions/501379/cant-use-3-monitors-both-display-outputs-on-xps-laptop-along-with-laptop-displ

Answer (score 0):

Just want to confirm that it works. I have age old LG E1940S monitor which is not even full HD and also Dell's latest P2419H. Below are my connection:

```
XPS 15 L502X HDMI -> HDMI to VGA adapter -> VGA cable -> LG monitor
XPS 15 L502X mini display port -> mini display port to HDMI cable -> Dell monitor
```

So total three screens including laptop's own screen. 
All working absolutely fine in both Duplicate and Extend modes of Windows 10.

Note that I havent done a single configuration. Just plugged in monitors and everything just worked out of box!!!

(PS: my laptop is also age old, XPS 15 2011 edition :D )