# Is it possible to use two external monitors with Dell XPS 15z?

Tags: multiple-monitors, dell-xps

On the Dell XPS 15z there are both an HDMI-port and a Mini DisplayPort. Is it possible to connect both of these at the same time as a way to get dual external monitors?

Related question for the XPS 15: [Is it possible to add 2 monitor to Dell XPS 15 Laptop?](https://superuser.com/questions/248088/is-it-possible-to-add-2-monitor-to-dell-xps-15-laptop)

Comment: I also really want to find this out...

Comment: But I did find this: http://forum.notebookreview.com/dell-xps-studio-xps/580742-new-xps-15z-28.html

Comment: @Shackrock Please see my answer, sorry for being late with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I emailed Dell support and asked, the answer was "yes, but you can't use the internal monitor at the same time". I have since tested this and can verify that it is true.

Comment: Great!  So basically any 2 monitors.  That works for me. thanks.