# connect two monitors to XPS 15 laptop

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displayport, dell-xps

I have an XPS 15 laptop with thunderbolt and hdmi and usb ports.
I want to connect it to two external monitors:
1. DELL P2715Q
2. LG 29UM68-P

[DELL P2715Q](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJkQZ.png)

[LG 29UM68-P](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGm93.png)

the spec sheet for LG says:

**HDMI** *2 (ver1.4)*

**DisplayPort** *Yes (ver1.2)*

there is a bit of instructions on how to do MST connections, but i am not sure if i can do it with this LG and how.

[DP MST connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32NNE.png)

I am clueless on how to do it without any external adapters or whatsoever.
Any tips or ideas?

Comment: Usually laptops only support two monitors at the same time. That means two external monitors work, but only of you disable the internal one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are the possible ways you could connect two displays on your laptop:

1. For [DP MST](https://blog.startech.com/post/connecting-multiple-monitors-multi-stream-transport-and-what-it-means-for-you/), you can do this:

   - Get a Thunderbolt-to-DP adapter and connect it to the Thunderbolt port of your laptop
   - Connect the output of the adapter to DP-IN (port 4) of your DELL monitor
   - DP-OUT (port 6) of the DELL monitor to the DP-IN of your LG monitor.
2. The next method is, connect one monitor via HDMI port and connect the other using Thunderbolt to any DP, HDMI, or a miniDP (for DELL-monitor only) adapter.
3. The easiest and most straight-forward solution might be to get a thunderbolt adapter with two DP outputs. Both of your monitors have DP-INs. [Thunderbolt](https://thunderbolttechnology.net/tech) can support two dual 4K displays. So, you can easily find 1 thunderbolt adapter with two display outputs.

Comment: coool, can you give an example of that adaptor you are talking about? the third solution i mean.

Comment: Plugable Thunderbolt 3 to Dual DisplayPort [link](https://www.amazon.com/Plugable-Thunderbolt-DisplayPort-Compatible-Supports/dp/B01F81EIBC/ref=sr_1_3?ie=UTF8&qid=1536961394&sr=8-3&keywords=Plugable+Thunderbolt+3+Dual+DisplayPort+Adapter&dpID=31k2riIZmEL&preST=_SX300_QL70_&dpSrc=srch) is an example. There are many others.

Comment: i tried any combination of the cables u mentioned, none worked. i am gonna try this adaptor.

Comment: only the adapter solution worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Run a HDMI cable to the LG and a Thunderbolt cable to the mini DisplayPort input on the Dell.

Am I missing something?

Comment: why thunderbolt to mDP and not DP ? any specific reason?

Comment: No specific reason other than your requirement to avoid adapters... Although these cables come in all flavors without separate adapters, some could be considered more "adapter like" than others :D

Comment: so a USB C to DP to DELL and HDMI to HDMI on LG ? right?

Comment: Sure, you didn't link your laptop's ports spec, but if your Thunderbolt on there is USB C than yes.

Comment: cool, yeah it is XPS 15 9560 and has hdmi and USB C, thanks

Comment: Great, have fun, you're welcome!

Comment: it doesn't work, i attached a hdmi to LG and USB C to DELL monitor (USB C to DP) and it only shows on LG monitor. HDMI takes over the USB C. I am not sure if it is possible this way.

Comment: See this Q&A: https://superuser.com/questions/407949/is-it-possible-to-use-two-external-monitors-with-dell-xps-15z?rq=1